# how to import/export jars with included old version external jars?

Tags: java, log4j

I have project "A" which includes `log4j.jar` (log4j version 1.2).
I export this project "A" as `A.jar`.

When someone have log4J updated version (1.2.17) and he imports my A project (import A.jar) , he gets class not found error (because  log4j is not the same version)

Is there a way to solve this, without creating new version of `A.jar` (with the updated log4j jar) ?

Comment: How are project A and the dependant project handling their dependencies? If you are using Maven or Gradle, you can exclude dependencies (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html and https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies respectively). If you're exporting from Eclipse, this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430333/how-to-pack-jar-file-without-containing-depedency-jar-libraries-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into a classic *dependency management* problem.

The long-term solution is to use a build tool designed for this - in Java probably the best place to start for this is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but also consider [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) as a more single-purpose tool.

With either you can specify what version of libraries you depend upon (and *when*, in your build / runtime lifecycle), and  get them from a global repository where necessary.

Comment: Thanks. So I will use maven in order to build A.jar,
Does others (which use my A.jar) need to use maven too ?

Comment: Ideally both do. You want your build to _specify_ that it needs `log4j`, but not _bundle_ that directly. 

Then the other project can pull your JAR directly, or if they use Maven it will know from the POM that it needs `log4j`, so they can specify which versions to include (or exclude) in _their_ project to sort out the class not found errors.